# Error while running dataflow job via Airflow: module 'apache_beam.io' has no attribute 'ReadFromBigQuery

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am having some issues when try to execute a DataFlow job orchestrated by Airflow. After triggered the DAG, i receive this error:

**module 'apache_beam.io' has no attribute 'ReadFromBigQuery''**

```
[2021-05-05 19:35:31,279] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 559673: Subtask exec_df_job [2021-05-05 19:35:31,278] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:121} INFO - Running command: python /tmp/dataflow50825def-pipeline.py --runner=DataflowRunner --project=project_name --temp_location=gs://tmp/ --runner=DataflowRunner --save_main_session=True --requirements_file=https://storage.cloud.google.com/df-jobs/requirements.txt --beam_plugins=[gcp] --labels=airflow-version=v1-10-6-composer --job_name=job-name-a6fe02fb --region=us-central1
[2021-05-05 19:35:31,516] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 559673: Subtask exec_df_job [2021-05-05 19:35:31,516] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:152} INFO - Start waiting for DataFlow process to complete.
[2021-05-05 19:35:42,605] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 559673: Subtask exec_df_job [2021-05-05 19:35:42,603] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:133} WARNING - b'/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/__init__.py:84: UserWarning: Some syntactic constructs of Python 3 are not yet fully supported by Apache Beam.\n  \'Some syntactic constructs of Python 3 are not yet fully supported by \'\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/dataflow50825def-pipeline.py", line 94, in <module>\n    run()\n  File "/tmp/dataflow50825def-pipeline.py", line 83, in run\n    | "Writes to BQ" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(\nAttributeError: module \'apache_beam.io\' has no attribute \'ReadFromBigQuery\''
[2021-05-05 19:35:42,613] {taskinstance.py:1059} ERROR - DataFlow failed with return code 1
```

Inside my DAG definition file, i have something like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataFlowPythonOperator

default_args = {
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 4, 27),
    'catchup': False,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5),
}

with DAG(
        dag_id='test_dataflow_jobs',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=None
) as dag:

    dataflow_default_options = {
        'project': 'project-name',
        'temp_location': 'gs://tmp/',
        'runner': 'DataflowRunner',
        'save_main_session': 'True',
        'extra_packages': 'apache-beam[gcp]==2.28.0'

    }

    options = {
        'requirements_file': 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/df-jobs/requirements.txt',
        'beam_plugins': "['gcp']"
    }

    exec_df_job = DataFlowPythonOperator(
        task_id='exec_df_job',
        gcp_conn_id='google-cloud-default',
        py_file='gs://df-jobs/pipeline.py',
        job_name='job-name',
        dataflow_default_options=dataflow_default_options,
        options=options
    )
```

And finally, my apache beam pipeline:

```py
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from argparse import ArgumentParser

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromBigQuery, WriteToBigQuery
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

sql_query = """SELECT * FROM my_table"""

table_schema = {'fields': [
  {'name': 'a', 'type': 'INTEGER', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
  {'name': 'b', 'type': 'BOOLEAN', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
  {'name': 'c', 'type': 'DATETIME', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}]}


def parse_data(record):
    pass


def run(argv=None):
    parser = ArgumentParser()

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    
    pipe = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    input_data = (
        pipe
        | "Reads data from bigquery" >> ReadFromBigQuery(query=sql_query, use_standard_sql=True)
        | "Map cnpj output" >> beam.Map(parse_data)
        | "Writes to BQ" >> WriteToBigQuery(
                                table="table_name",
                                dataset="dataset_name",
                                project="project_name",
                                schema=table_schema)
    )

    pipe.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

The curious thing is that running the same job via command line, the pipeline is successfully executed, without errors.

Executing via cli:

```sh
python3 pipeline.py --temp_location gs://tmp/ --project project_name --runner DataflowRunner --region us-central1 --name job_name
```

[image]

Please, help me :(

Comment: Are you sure `apache-beam[gcp]` was installed into your airflow environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The main problem of this question is:** The famous: On my machine it works, that is, different framework versions.

After installing the `apache-beam[gcp]` on my Cloud Composer environment (Apache Airflow), i noticed that the version of Apache Beam SDK is 2.15.0 and does not have `ReadFromBigQuery` and `WriteToBigQuery` implemented.

We are using this version because is the one compatible with our Composer Version. After changing my code, everything works as well

```py
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from argparse import ArgumentParser

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromBigQuery, WriteToBigQuery
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

sql_query = """SELECT * FROM my_table"""

# Needed to change how to declare the schema
table_schema = ('a:INTEGER, b:BOOLEAN, c:DATETIME')


def parse_data(record):
    pass


def run(argv=None):
    parser = ArgumentParser()

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    
    pipe = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    input_data = (
        pipe
        | "Reads data from bigquery" >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=sql_query, use_standard_sql=True))
        | "Map cnpj output" >> beam.Map(parse_data)
        | "Writes to BQ" >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(
                                'project_name:dataset_name.table_name',
                                schema=table_schema,
                                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
                             )
    )

    pipe.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

**And why my old code works?**

Again, because a different version of Apache Beam. As i am using ubuntu 20.04 and the last version of pip, when i ran `pip3 install 'apache-beam[gcp]'`, the package manager installed the 2.29.0 SDK version.

Now, i created a development environment with the same version of my Composer environment and planning to update my Composer and Airflow version, and consequently my PyPi packages.